# When showing Fields as the format on a Views RSS feed, what should I set the GUID to?

Tags: views, feeds

I have a Views feed that I want to show as fields to customize the display.  As you can see from the screenshot, I have configured the fields in the appropriate rows.  However, I don't know what to set as the GUID.  Should it be the title?  The link?  Is there a "default" setting for this?

[image: RSS field configuration]